# drupal include php file from web

Tags: php, drupal

I want to

```
include("http://domain.com/file.php")
```

in either my drupal module or theme.

but I get

```
Failed opening required 'http://domain.com/file.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')
```

what is the correct way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini. Get more info [here](http://www.madirish.net/?article=427)

Answer (score 1):

That is the proper way. However `allow_url_include` needs to be set to true in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version need to be >= 4.3.0.

You need to enable the "allow_url_fopen" in your *php.ini* file:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

I suggest you to read on the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function in php.net.